# Is there any way to create a dependcy graph for a solidity smart contract?

Tags: solidity

I'm trying to build a tool for Solidity static analysis. As the AST can be generated for the compiler.
So I wonder if there are already tools to generate the program dependency graph for the solidity smart contract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Solidity Visual Developer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tintinweb.solidity-visual-auditor) VSCode extension offers this feature, among many others:

[image: VSCode Extension preview]

Answer (score 2):

you can use https://github.com/ConsenSys/surya .

> Surya is an utility tool for smart contract systems. It provides a number of visual outputs and information about the contracts' structure. Also supports querying the function call graph in multiple ways to aid in the manual inspection of contracts.